# How to get the drupal version using phpMyAdmin query?

Tags: 7, database

How to get the drupal version using query ? Or
how do we detect using query the drupal version is 7,6,5 or 4?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887282/how-to-find-version-of-drupal-installed) is relevant however whilst does give you lots of options doesn't actually say how to get this from the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work with Drupal 7 - I don't have other version to test it on but think it should work...

Because the version is stored in the text file CHANGELOG.txt we can write that to a table in the DB, read from the table, and then delete it again afterwards:

First run this: (make sure to change the path to your changelog file)

```
CREATE TABLE `drupal_version` (`data`  varchar(255) NULL);
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/www/your_site/htdocs/CHANGELOG.txt' INTO TABLE drupal_version;
SELECT * FROM drupal_version WHERE data LIKE "%Drupal%" LIMIT 1;
```

This will return something like:

```
Drupal 7.26, 2014-01-15
```

And run this to delete the table we just made:

```
DROP TABLE drupal_version;
```

Whilst this is a long winded way of reading text from a text file it is strictly speaking getting the version using MySQL...

### Second Option

As Topsitemakers suggested looking in the system table I had a look and found the version was hidden in there, but only against specific modules. I figured the field module would be in all version of drupal, however I very highly doubt that this query will actually work on any version other that 7 as it's so specific and a bit of a beast:

```
SELECT MID(info, LOCATE(':"', info, LOCATE('"version";', info)) + 2, MID(info, LOCATE('"version";', info) + 12, LOCATE(':"', info, LOCATE('"version";', info)) - LOCATE('"version";', info) - 12))
FROM system WHERE filename LIKE "%/field.module"
```

For me this query returns:

```
7.26
```

Comment: Now, this is a smart way to answer to what the OP ASKED. :-)

Comment: This is...hideous!! Kudos for answering the question exactly as it was posed, but I hope the OP knows better than to actually use either of these methods for anything real :)

Comment: Ha ha ha - hideous... I completely agree :)

Answer (score 2):

Open `modules/system/system.info` file and check out the value of `core` item.
The value will tell you the version, e.g. 6.x/7.x/8.x.

Comment: how to check for drupal version 5,4?

Comment: I'm not sure if the version of Drupal even stored in the DB. I just searched the whole db for "version" and nothing promising came up...

Comment: @harshal AFAIK D4/D5 don't have the `core` value but have `version` which will tell you the core info. @FelixEve the information in `system` table might help; I'm not sure though of its schema in D4 though.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for D7 and D6, i don't have other versions to test but if system table is similar, it should work as well.

```
SELECT MAX(schema_version) FROM system;
```

This will get something like "7002" or some number starting with a 7 for Drupal 7 and "6005" or something starting with 6 for Drupal 6.
It's not the exact running version but if you just have a database dump you can figure out from where it comes from.

Comment: This is the best answer for the case where I have a DB, but not a running drupal system.